# How to Calculate Bin Averages using Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataset of about 12000 rows. The data consists of displacement values and time stamp. For every 10 rows, i want to calculate the mean, std dev variance etc.

Can i use the window function feature for this ? Or can someone suggest a simpler way ?

P.S : I'm new to Spark and scala. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you come up with yourself? How do you compute the bins? You could do a `reduceByKey` operation, where the key is the appropriate bin.

Comment: Binsize is not defined beforehand. It is an input parameter from the user. I dont think reduceByKey can solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

yes use `rolling windows` with `lag`, `lead`, `rowsBetween` etc plenty options available depending on your use case here are some links: [windows explained](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) [more windows info](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-windows.html)

Comment: Do you know any way to increase the step size/sliding size of the window function ? by default it is set to 1.

Comment: As far as i know, Window functions will calculate the results of every row, with overlapping. I want one result per bin. i.e, average of 10 rows. then average of next 10 rows.  [1-10 - bin1,11-20 -bin2 ] and so on.

Comment: pls paste your code - data frame and desired output